# Почему окна приложений не остаются на внешнем мониторе?

Tags: macos, macbook

у меня MacBook подключён к внешнему монитору по type-c.

каждый раз, когда я вывожу систему из спящего режима, все окна (которые не на полный экран) возвращаются на экран ноутбука, хотя до сна они были на внешнем мониторе.

как это исправить? спасибо

Comment: Че за type-c? thunderbolt 4 чтоли? а с другой стороны какой разъём?

Comment: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/moom/id419330170?mt=12

Comment: @DiD да, thunderbolt. на мониторе тоже такой разъём